# Stripe API: Can´t use the raw body with express

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, backend

So I´m trying to verify the transactions using Stripe and it needs the raw body to verify the request.

Stripe Docs on that topic: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures

my code:

```
router.post(
  "/stripe_webhook",
  express.raw({ type: "application/json" }),
  (request, response) => {
    updateStripePaymentStatus(request, response);
  }
);

exports.updateStripePaymentStatus = async (request, response) => {
  const sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  //Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case "payment_intent.succeeded":
      const paymentIntent = event.data.object;

      const doc = await FileModel.findOne({ paymentId: paymentIntent.id });

      doc.paymentStatus = paymentIntent.status;

      doc.save();

      break;

    default:
      // Unexpected event type
      console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}.`);
  }

  // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.send();
};
```

Error: message: 'No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? [https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing'](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing%27),

The secret and and so on should work and all. But if I console.log the request.body it still returns a jason object instead of a string...

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a number of things. There's probably something in your stack that modifying the request body. Take a look at these issues for some clues: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/341 and https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/356.

Comment: Hey man! Yes it was actually another middleware which was applied before the rawbody convertment. 
Had to put the route before that middleware and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

1. Replace `express.raw({ type: "application/json" })` --> `express.raw()`
2. Replace `stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret)` --> `stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req["rawBody"], sig, endpointSecret)`